# Fun question in additive combinatorics

Tags: additive-combinatorics, co.combinatorics, arithmetic-progression

It is easy to see that for a finite set of integers $A$ of cardinality $n$, the cardinality of the sumset $A+A$ satisfies
$$
2n-1\leq |A+A|\leq \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
$$

The lower bound is essentially attained when the set $A$ is an arithmetic progression while the upper bound is attained for sets such that $a_{i}+a_{j}=a_{p}+a_{q}$ implies that $\{i,j\}=\{p,q\}$. An example of this set is

$$
A=\{2^{i}:i={0,1,\ldots,n-1}\}.
$$

I think is a fun problem (probably not very difficult) to study what is the rate of growth of $|A_{p}+A_{p}|$ as $n\to\infty$ where 
$$
A_p=\{1^p,2^p,\ldots,n^p\}.
$$

Define the "asymptotic growth exponent" as
$$
\mathrm{ge_{p}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} {\frac{\log(|A_{p}+A_{p}|)}{\log(n)}}.
$$

What is the limit $\mathrm{ge_{p}}$ for $p=2$? In general?

Enjoy! :-)

Comment: This is not meant as criticism but will determine if any or how much time I spent on this question: do you have a serious interest in this, or is this for fun only?

Comment: Is this a question to which you already know the answer?

Comment: If I've understood the question, surely the limit is 2 for all $p$. For squares this is just the fact that $\gg N^{1-o(1)}$ integers less than $N$ are the sum of two squares. For larger $p$ it's certainly known (I don't have a reference to hand). And is $p$ supposed to be an integer?

Comment: Skinner and Wooley is the reference I have in mind, I believe.

Comment: One way of putting Ben's comment when p=2 is to say that it's known that every prime of the form 4m+1 is a sum of two squares. It's easy to see from that that the limit is 2 when p=2. For larger p one would expect the limit to be at least as big, and this is indeed the case.

Comment: @gowers: I don't see the relation between the fact that every prime of the form $4m+1$ can be written as a sum of two squares with my question. The intuition under the fact that the limit is 2 is that there are very few possibilities for $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ with $\{a,b\}\neq\{c,d\}$ and $a,b,c,d\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. I'm sure that I'm missing something elementary here. Thanks! 

Comment: @GHT: The relation is that if one can show that A_p + A_p is large enough then one is done. The argument shows that the set contains all primes fulfilling the congruence relation up to n^2 (as they have some rep., and this rep. cannot involve a square not in A_p). The number of such primes is assymp. n^2 / (2 log n^2) . Giving a lower bound. Taking the log of this bound one gets something of the form 2 log n + o(log n) and thus is done.   